# Как приготовить приложение на python для пользователя

Tags: python

Написал змейку на питоне с использованием библиотеки pygame, встал вопрос о распространении кода друзьям, но я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы друзьям не пришлось устанавливать интерпретатор, библиотеку pygame и в целом запускать скрипт через консоль. Знаю, что вариант с exe-файлами не прокатит, т.к. питон — язык интерпретируемый, а не компилируемый. Так вот, есть ли какие-нибудь лайфхаки?

Comment: Чего же не прокатит-то. Есть компиляторы в ехе.

Comment: cxFreeze и подобное. Уточню, это не компиляция будет, а упаковка в exe  интерпретатора и скриптов твоих. Ну и конечно же ты всегда можешь замутить инсталлятор.